How to spawn a child process in a python-embedded frozen application?
As far as I know, in python multiprocessing module, the entry function of a child process is the function: multiprocessing.spawn.spawn_main.
According to the following function (multiprocessing.spawn.get_command_line):
def get_command_line(**kwds):
    '''
    Returns prefix of command line used for spawning a child process
    '''
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        return ([sys.executable, '--multiprocessing-fork'] +
                ['%s=%r' % item for item in kwds.items()])
    else:
        prog = 'from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(%s)'
        prog %= ', '.join('%s=%r' % item for item in kwds.items())
        opts = util._args_from_interpreter_flags()
        exe = get_executable()
        return [exe] + opts + ['-c', prog, '--multiprocessing-fork']

In normal python, the spawned worker process on Windows looks as follows:
python.exe -c "from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(parent_pid=6872, pipe_handle=520)" --multiprocessing-fork

While in a frozen python embedded application, the spawned worker process on Windows looks as follows:
my_program.exe --multiprocessing-fork parent_pid=8752 pipe_handle=1552

So I think I need to manually call the multiprocessing.spawn.spawn_main when I find a --multiprocessing-fork from the arguments.
Here is my C++ code:
#include <Python.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <filesystem>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>

static int multiprocess_main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc < 4)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Too little arguments to know how to run a python multiprocess.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    PyStatus status;

    PyConfig config;
    PyConfig_InitPythonConfig(&config);
    config.module_search_paths_set = 1; // sys.path will be: ['']

    std::filesystem::path executable_path(argv[0]);
    auto                  executable_directory = executable_path.parent_path().wstring();

    config.write_bytecode = 0;

    // In Python3.11, this will not work.
    // See: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/106718
    status = PyConfig_SetString(&config, &config.stdlib_dir, executable_directory.c_str());
    if (PyStatus_Exception(status))
    {
        PyConfig_Clear(&config);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", PyStatus_IsError(status) != 0 ? status.err_msg : "Failed to set sys._stdlib_dir.");
        return 1;
    }
    status = Py_InitializeFromConfig(&config);
    if (PyStatus_Exception(status))
    {
        PyConfig_Clear(&config);
        fprintf(stderr, "%s", PyStatus_IsError(status) != 0 ? status.err_msg : "Failed to initialize CPython from config.");
        return 1;
    }

    PyConfig_Clear(&config);

    int exitcode = 0;
    // Set sys._stdlib_dir manually
    PyObject* stdlib_dir_value;

    const auto* stdlibdir = executable_directory.c_str();

    stdlib_dir_value = PyUnicode_FromWideChar(stdlibdir, wcslen(stdlibdir));
    if (stdlib_dir_value == nullptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not convert directory name to unicode\n");
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }
    if (PySys_SetObject("_stdlib_dir", stdlib_dir_value) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not set sys._stdlib_dir\n");
        Py_DECREF(stdlib_dir_value);
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }
    Py_DECREF(stdlib_dir_value);
    // Set sys.frozen
    if (PySys_SetObject("frozen", Py_True) == -1)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not set sys.frozen\n");
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }

    // Set "--multiprocessing-fork" to sys.argv to make multiprocessing.spawn.is_forking work
    PyRun_SimpleString("import sys; sys.argv.append('--multiprocessing-fork')");

    // from multiprocessing.spawn import spawn_main; spawn_main(parent_pid=xxx, pipe_handle=yyy)
    // Currently only win32 is supported
    PyObject *spawn, *spawn_main, *spawnargs, *parent_pid, *pipe_handle, *result;
    for (int arg_idx = 2; arg_idx < argc; arg_idx++)
    {
        std::stringstream        argss(argv[arg_idx]);
        std::string              segment;
        std::vector<std::string> seglist;
        while (std::getline(argss, segment, '='))
        {
            seglist.push_back(segment);
        }
        if (seglist[0] == "parent_pid")
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "parent_pid=%s\n", seglist[1].c_str());
            parent_pid = PyLong_FromString(seglist[1].c_str(), nullptr, 0);
            if (parent_pid == nullptr)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse parent_pid=%s while starting multiprocess\n", seglist[2].c_str());
                if (pipe_handle != nullptr)
                {
                    Py_DECREF(pipe_handle);
                }
                PyErr_Print();
                return 1;
            }
        }
        if (seglist[0] == "pipe_handle")
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "pipe_handle=%s\n", seglist[1].c_str());
            pipe_handle = PyLong_FromString(seglist[1].c_str(), nullptr, 0);
            if (pipe_handle == nullptr)
            {
                fprintf(stderr, "Failed to parse pipe_handle=%s while starting multiprocess\n", seglist[2].c_str());
                if (parent_pid != nullptr)
                {
                    Py_DECREF(parent_pid);
                }
                PyErr_Print();
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    if (pipe_handle == nullptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not parse pipe_handle while starting multiprocess\n");
        return 1;
    }
    spawn = PyImport_ImportModule("multiprocessing.spawn");
    if (spawn == nullptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not import multiprocessing.spawn\n");
        Py_DECREF(pipe_handle);
        if (parent_pid != nullptr)
        {
            Py_DECREF(parent_pid);
        }
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }
    spawn_main = PyObject_GetAttrString(spawn, "spawn_main");
    if (spawn_main == nullptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not access function: multiprocessing.spawn.spawn_main\n");
        Py_DECREF(spawn);
        Py_DECREF(pipe_handle);
        if (parent_pid != nullptr)
        {
            Py_DECREF(parent_pid);
        }
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }
    if (parent_pid != nullptr)
    {
        spawnargs = PyTuple_Pack(2, pipe_handle, parent_pid);
    }
    else
    {
        spawnargs = PyTuple_Pack(1, pipe_handle);
    }
    if (spawnargs == nullptr)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not create arguments for multiprocessing.spawn.spawn_main\n");
        Py_DECREF(spawn);
        Py_DECREF(spawn_main);
        Py_DECREF(pipe_handle);
        if (parent_pid != nullptr)
        {
            Py_DECREF(parent_pid);
        }
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }
    result = PyObject_Call(spawn_main, spawnargs, nullptr);
    Py_DECREF(spawn);
    Py_DECREF(spawn_main);
    Py_DECREF(spawnargs);
    Py_DECREF(pipe_handle);
    if (parent_pid != nullptr)
    {
        Py_DECREF(parent_pid);
    }
    if (result == nullptr)
    {
        PyErr_Print();
        return 1;
    }
    Py_DECREF(result);
    return exitcode;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if (argc >= 2 && strcmp(argv[1], "--multiprocessing-fork") == 0)
    {
        return multiprocess_main(argc, argv);
    }

    // Other normal stuffs
}

The test python script is as follows:
import multiprocessing
from multiprocessing import spawn


def f():
    print("hello world!")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    multiprocessing.freeze_support()
    multiprocessing.Process(target=f).start()

But I got the output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen multiprocessing.spawn>", line 113, in spawn_main
  File "<frozen multiprocessing.reduction>", line 79, in duplicate
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied

Every time after building the executable, I got the above output when I run it for the first time. After that, what I got is as follows (No matter how many times I run it):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<frozen multiprocessing.spawn>", line 108, in spawn_main
OSError: [WinError 87] The parameter is incorrect

I have no idea what's going on here, can anybody help me? Thanks!
I expect child process can be spawned successfully on Windows.
